# STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED in Android

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am implementing the necessary code. But when I try to submit the score I am getting this error. I tried out the solutions provided in answers to different questions, but I couldn't solve my problem.

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupView();
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(),
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_winner),
                    numGuesses).setResultCallback(new myLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
            numGuesses++;
            break;
        case R.id.bests:
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_winner)), 2);
            break;
    }
}
```

Android Manifest Permisssions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Random `case` statements in a method are not legal. Are you omitting a `switch` statement?

Comment: Yes when I add here I m forget it to copy  that. I edit now

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes.html#constants), **STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED** error means that a network error occurred while attempting to perform an operation that requires network access. There is a possibility that you are not signed in when this error occurs. Make sure to perform some sort of check, such as `getGamesClient.isConnected()` or `isSignedIn()`.

Also, maybe you are submitting a score greater than the one you have configured on the console to be the min value for that leaderboard.

Comment: Thanks. But I checked now but still return same error and sign is return true and i configured 1 for min value but i am trying to add 10.Is there a problem on my permission?Is it enough?